# What's the Best Way to Implement Paging with a List using jQuery Mobile and MVC?

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a media library from a tutorial to get up to speed on MVC 4. I did the whole thing and now I'm re-building it using jQuery Mobile. The only piece I've yet to find simple is paging which should be easy. Can someone steer me in the direction of a nice tutorial on the subject?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Are the items in the list being populated via a database? If so, do you want each page loaded via AJAX or a page refresh? Can the DOM simply be paged using JavaScript? etc...?

Answer (score 0):

We do have similar kind of Use case.

Store the Data in Session object in the form of Dictionary  in this form.

On click of Next or previous button in Pagination control, fetch data from Controller, bind data to appropriate control in the UI and show data.

Make sure to show only limited data in UI. Restrict the number[max 10 per page]

Format Dictionary